# how do you enable command line editing with vim keys using mac terminal?

Tags: terminal

I'm reading this book and I really do not understand what this author is talking about. It appears that you can program your mac to go forward one character by either hitting l or ^F.  I do not understand the difference between emac key stroke and vim keystroke.  He also says run this command and 'place it in your $HOME/.bash_profile but I cannot figure out how to place the command in the bas_profile. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Author is talking about make you terminal console behaves like `vi`, this means typing `set -o vi` in your terminal, the console will work similar `vi`. So you will be able to navigate using the motion keys of `vi`, use `INSERT` mode, `x` to delete, etc.

You can set that permanently if you include this command in your `~/.bash_profile` file.

If you are not sure what it does, I don't recommend so.